# Cordova/Ionic IAP not always works

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase

I have made my Cordova/Ionic app with in app purchases. During test period all works fine, published it live in Google Play and App Store all seems to be fine. Get lots of purchases, tested it myself on different devices and all seems ok. But then after a week the first email came in they purchases an IAP and it was not unlocked (iOS, have any issues heared from Android users). Tow weeks later a second... now I have like 15 people where is does not work and I have seen prove that they have purchased it.

I am using this IAP plugin:
https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase

Before that one I used another IAP plugin, but because of the same problem I started to use the first one:
https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase

I also made a issue post on github but still no answer:
As I am not allowed to post more links atm, it is issue 113.

The code I use works in 99.9%:

```
loadProducts = function () {
$ionicLoading.show({ template: spinner + 'Loading...' });
        inAppPurchase
            .getProducts(productIds)
            .then(function (products) {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                // Load all products by ID
                products.forEach(function (product) {
                    // Add extra field to the product object
                    product.owned = false;
                    switch (product.productId) {
                        case ncProductProVer:
                            if (GlobalVars.vars.fullVersion == true) {
                                product.owned = true;
                            }
                            break;
                        case ncProductNoAds:
                            if (GlobalVars.vars.noAds == true) {
                                product.owned = true;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                });
                //alert(products[0].productId + ' ' + products[1].productId);
                $scope.products = products;
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                //$cordovaDialogs.alert('Error loading products. Details:\n- Code: ' + err.code + '\n- Message: ' +  err.message, 'Error', 'OK')
                $scope.CodeError = true;
            });
};

// BUY a product
$scope.buy = function (productId) {
    $ionicLoading.show({ template: spinner + 'Buying...' });
    inAppPurchase
        .buy(productId)
        .then(function (data) {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            enableIAP(productId, true);
        })
        .then(function () {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            loadProducts();
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            errHandling(err.code, productId);
        });
};

// RESTORE in app purchases
$scope.restore = function () {
    $ionicLoading.show({ template: spinner + 'Restoring purchases...' });
            inAppPurchase
                .restorePurchases()
                .then(function (purchases) {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    purchases.forEach(function (purchase) {
                        // Unlock the relevant feature based on this product id, if any
                        // Store the purchase in localStorage
                        enableIAP(purchase.productId, true);
                    });
                    // Reload the productlist
                    loadProducts();
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                });
};
```

I have tried many different things already, but cant figure out what the problem can be or how I can see what goes wrong as the app runs on a device where I don't have access to :).

The only thing I have is that people say the 'Buying...' popup keeps on loading till they close the app and run it again. So the problem must me in the .buy() function and does not give a error back but otherwise it will be in the .catch().

Things I can think of is:
- Apple does not always sends the same string back
- The string send back from Apple contains chars that are not correctly handled by the IAP code

To make things more odd, I managed to get in contact with somebody where it did not work. So I started testing some things as I thought maybe it could be device settings. So I had the iPhone and signed in with my iTunes account, downloaded the app and restored the IAP and it worked. Did the same thing, sign in with their iTunes account, did not work. That person also had an iPad mini, where it all worked as expected, the extra item in the app where unlocked as they should.

Anybody seen this strange behaviour? Been busy many weeks/months already to figure out what it could be.